# Wordpress Restrict Page Editing by User/Role

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a Wordpress plugin that can create per-page user editing permissions. What I mean by this is that I am looking for a plugin that can say that only specific users or specific roles can edit specific pages.

Can anyone recommend a (preferably free) plugin that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution: install and combine the Members (https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/) and Co-Authors Plus (https://wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors-plus/) plugins. On each page, add the user you want to have editing access as an author. From there, change the role settings as necessary.